# Will it be possible to vote for migrating a question from superuser.com to stackoverflow or servefault?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

I know some questions are moved from SO to SU.

Will SU moderators be able to do a migration from SU to SO/SF ?
(I just dont have enough points to test how migration works myself :) )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has already been done more than once.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22migrated+from+superuser.com%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) turns up a few migrated questions, although most of the results are from meta.stackoverflow.com.

#### Some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136890/remove-a-specific-file-from-a-subversion-repository
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152340/why-are-developers-generally-opposed-to-purchasing-software-tools
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140311/using-python-to-automate-creation-manipulation-of-excel-spreadsheets
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178475/looking-for-a-free-java-ide